# how to show in a table a complete string below the other with split(";")

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

### I have a problem, I receive a whole long string in a table, which is separated by ";",
what I need to do is divide by ; and show me one below the other, for example in the image in the third field, it would be something like:
general data

### Delivery day: 90
Delivery date:

And so one below the other, I was doing my functionalities in the function below.
Thank you very much for helping me!! thank you

[image]

```
<template>
 <v-card>
 <v-card-title>
  Control Modificaciones
 </v-card-title>
 <v-card-text>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" md="3" class="ml-3">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="fechaDesde"
        type="date"
        label="Fecha Desde"
        :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Este campo es requiredo']"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" md="3" class="ml-3">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="fechaHasta"
        type="date"
        label="Fecha Hasta"
        :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Este campo es requiredo']"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-btn color="info" title="Crear" class="mt-6 ml-8" @click="buscar()">
      Buscar
    </v-btn>
  </v-row>
</v-card-text>


<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" md="12" class="ml-3">
    <v-dialog
      v-model="popupPresupuestoHistorial"
      class="ml-10"
      max-width="100%"
      max-height="700px"
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="text-h3 dark lighten-2">
          Listado de Presupuesto Historial.
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-simple-table>
            <template>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-left">Fecha</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Comentario</th>
                  <!-- <th class="text-left">Usuario</th> -->
                  <th class="text-left">Datos Generales</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Articulos Nuevos</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Articulos Modifados</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Articulos Eliminados</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in presupuestoHistorial" :key="item.id">
                  <td>{{ formatDate(item.fecha) }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.observacion }}</td>
                  <!-- <td>{{ item.usuario.name }}</td> -->
                  <td>{{ item.datosCabecera }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.articulosNuevos }}</td>
                  <td>
                    {{ item.articulosModificados }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{ item.articulosEliminados }}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </template>
          </v-simple-table>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            text
            color="primary"
            @click="popupPresupuestoHistorial = false"
          >
            Cancelar
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

```
<script>
 export default {
 name: "ControlModificaciones",
data() {
return {
  fechaHasta: null,
  fechaDesde: null,
  list: [],
  presupuestoHistorial: [],
  popupPresupuestoHistorial: false,
};
},
created() {
 this.presupuestoServices = new PresupuestoServices();
 },
mounted() {},
methods: {

buscar() {
  if (this.fechaDesde == null && this.fechaHasta == null) {
    Swal.fire("Primero debes seleccionar las fechas.");
    return;
  }
  const fechaDesde = this.fechaDesde != null ? this.fechaDesde : null;
  const fechaHasta = this.fechaHasta != null ? this.fechaHasta : null;

  Swal.fire({
    title: "Espere unos momentos ...",
    showConfirmButton: false,
  });
  this.presupuestoServices
    .controlModificaciones(fechaDesde, fechaHasta)
    .then((data) => {
      Swal.close();
      this.list = data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      Swal.close();
      this.showError(error.response.data);
    });
},
abrirPopupListadoPresupuestoHistorial(item) {
  this.popupPresupuestoHistorial = true;
  this.presupuestoHistorial = item.presupuestoHistorial;
  // console.log(this.presupuestoHistorial.datosCabecera.split(";"));

  this.presupuestoHistorial.map(function(item) {
    var articuloNew = item.articulosNuevos.split(";");
    console.log(articuloNew.map((e) => e));

    var datosCabecera = item.datosCabecera.split(";");
    console.log(datosCabecera.map((e) => e));

    var articulosEliminados = item.articulosEliminados.split(";");
    console.log(articulosEliminados.map(e => e))

    var articulosModificados = item.articulosModificados.split(";");
    console.log(articulosModificados.map(e => e))
    // return articuloNew;
  });
  },
 },
 };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `td` where that is required in a `p` tag and apply appropriate line breaks.

Something like:

```html
...
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="item in presupuestoHistorial" :key="item.id">
    <td>{{ formatDate(item.fecha) }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.observacion }}</td>
    <!-- <td>{{ item.usuario.name }}</td> -->
    <td>
      <!-- replace all semicolons with \n -->
      <p>{{ item.datosCabecera.replaceAll(';', '\n') }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>{{ item.articulosNuevos }}</td>
    <td>
      {{ item.articulosModificados }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ item.articulosEliminados }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
...

<style scoped lang="scss">
td {
  p {
    /* this makes it so \n is treated as line break */
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, but is there another way to make it neater with split? Or is this the only one?

Comment: By `String.split()`? That will give you an array, and I guess you could do something like `<p v-for="line of item.datosCabecera.split(':')">{{ line }}</p>` if you want to do some kind of additional styling with it.

Comment: @cSharp did you tried this `item.datosCabecera.replaceAll(';', '\n')` ? It will not add a line break.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal you have to add appropriate css to it as well, the `white-space: pre-line`.

Answer (score 0):

I had thought of doing something like this, it is returning things to me but I need to be able to show them in the table

[image]